# How to fit a function with an integral in python

Tags: python, data-analysis, curve-fitting, integral

I have to fit a fairly complex function to the data of an experiment and so far I get values that makes no sense. The function looks like this [function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tCJE.gif). I have tried the following:

```
R0 = 2.5e-9 

def integrand1(r, args):
    t, W0, n = args
    return 4*pi*n*W0*np.exp(-2*r/R0)*np.exp(-W0*np.exp(-2*r/R0)*t)*r**2

def integrand2(r, args):
    t, W0, n = args
    return 4*pi*n*(np.exp(-W0*np.exp(-2*r/R0)*t)-1)*r**2

def fit(t, W0,n):
    res = scipy.integrate.quad(integrand1, 0.0, np.inf,[t,W0,n])*np.exp(scipy.integrate.quad(integrand2, 0, np.inf, [t,W0,n]))
    return res[0]

vcurve = np.vectorize(fit, excluded=set([1]))

popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(vcurve, t, y,p0=[0,0], bounds = ((0,0),(np.inf,1)))

print(popt)
print(pcov)
```

I'm really unsure how to proceed, because the code 'apparently' works but I either get an error of infinity or 0, which neither makes sense. I've never dealt with such a complicated function so I assume I may be missing some steps that may help me 'prevent' or fix this issue and make the fit work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit1: This is the seccond attempt at the fit:

```
def W(W0,r):
return W0*exp(-2*r/R0)


def I(t,W0,R0,n):
    out = []
    for i in t:
        t1 = 4*pi*n * quad(lambda r: W0 * exp(-2*r/R0 -W(W0,r)*i)*r**2,0,inf)[0]
        t2 = exp(4*pi*n * quad(lambda r: (exp(-W(W0,r)*i) - 1) * r**2,0,inf)[0])
        out.append(t1*t2/(pi*n*W0*R0**3)) #Normierung
    return out



pars = Parameters()
pars.add('W0', value=1,  min=0)
pars.add('n', value=1, min=0)
pars.add('R0', value=2.5e-9, vary = False)

mdl = Model(I)
result = mdl.fit(y,t,params=pars,nan_policy='propagate')
comps = result.eval_components()

print(result.fit_report())
```

Here I get the error message: fit() got multiple values for argument 'params'. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated!

For extra information, I(t) and t consists of 20000 rows. t goes from 0 to 3.2e^-5s and here is a sample of I(t): 14,19,18,10,10,15,15,23,16,74,54,44,31,31,26,39,31,46,31,23.

Comment: It's difficult to read your function. Can you edit your question with the mathematical description of the function you intend to integrate?

Comment: I added a picture of the function!

Comment: Is `r` a radius?

Comment: W(r) is the recombination probability of donors and acceptors in a semiconductor and r is the distance between them.